# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, exc-bad-access

sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm trying to write a program that compares 7 numbers that a user inputs to 7 numbers that the computer generates(a kind of lottery simulator). However, when i try to input the 7 numbers that the user inputs the program crashes after the second input. Please help, and thanks in advance!

This is the beginning of my main:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "Implementation.hpp"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    string name;
    cout << "What is your name?\n";
    getline(cin, name);
    while(1 != 0) //I know this will never be true, I'm just doing it       
                  //because the return statement will
    {             //end the program anyways if the user inputs 2
        int *userNums = new int[7];
        int *winningNums = new int[7];
        int cont;
        int matches;

        cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL\n";
        cout << "--------------------------\n";
        cout << "1) Play Lotto\n";
        cout << "2) Quit Program\n";
        cin >> cont;
        if(cont == 2)
            return 0;

        getLottoPicks(&userNums);
```

And this is the getLottoPicks function:

```
void getLottoPicks(int *picks[])
{
    int numsAdded = 0, choice;
    while(numsAdded <= 7)
    {
        cout << "Please input a valid number as your lotto decision.\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if(noDuplicates(*picks, choice) == false)
            continue;
        *picks[numsAdded] = choice;
        numsAdded++;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly certain that it is a problem with the pointers that i'm trying to use, but without them I can't actually change the arrays I don't think, and I couldn't get the function to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++, then you're probably better using a `std::vector<int>`, and passing in the reference to the vector in `getLottoPicks`.

However, your code should only be passing the `int *` to the getLottoPicks, and should process `< 7` items - it's the classic off-by one.

call to getLottoPicks:

```
getLottoPicks(userNums);
```

and the new getLottoPicks code:

```
void getLottoPicks(int *picks)
{
    int numsAdded = 0, choice;
    while(numsAdded < 7)
    {
        cout << "Please input a valid number as your lotto decision.\n";
        cin >> choice;
        if(noDuplicates(picks, choice) == false)
            continue;
        picks[numsAdded] = choice;
        numsAdded++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and for catching the off by one error, however the code won't compile when I try to pass (userNums) as the parameter instead of (&userNums), and taking the asterisk away from   

        picks[numsAdded] = choice;

causes it to not compile as well. Thanks again for the help and hopefully this issue isn't too serious.

Comment: The getLottoPicks signature has changed - it only takes an `int *` now, you'll have to make a similar change to the `noDuplicates` routine as well